# How to use .split() while setting an argument to skip a specific tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

I am trying to split all text group from a readme file, this is to get all the individual words, however words written inside the markdown syntax for embeding a URL.. `[]()` are showing unwanted results.

So, if I use `.split()` on this sentence

> The site uses the [stackoverlow api](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs)  to fetch all existing tags and create a

`.split()` will treat `[stackoverflow api](..` as two words and yield this result

```
>>> r = "The site uses the [stackoverlow api](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs)  to fetch"
>>> print(r.split())
['The', 'site', 'uses', 'the', '[stackoverlow', 'api](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs)', 'to', 'fetch']
>>>
```

Since this is unintended, is there way to ignore anything inside `[]()` or treat it as a single word?

Comment: I think the solution here is clearly to use a Markdown parser, not regular expressions. You could even convert the Markdown to HTML and then use a HTML parser to grab just the text content from it.

Comment: Yeah, I think the first solution is clearly the best way, I don't know why I didn't think of a markdown parser. I will look for a library that somehow only fetches word, as I am using regex to ignore every markdown syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution using `re.findall()` function:

```
import re

s = "The site uses the [stackoverlow api](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs)  to fetch"
result = re.findall(r'\[[^]]+\]\([^)]+\)|\S+', s)

print(result)
```

The output:

```
['The', 'site', 'uses', 'the', '[stackoverlow api](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs)', 'to', 'fetch']
```

---

- `\[[^]]+\]\([^)]+\)` - matches sequence `[...](...)` as a single item
- `\S+` - matches non-whitespace character sequence (word)

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to escape the `]` in `\[[^]]` - this might look like an empty negated character class to some people. `\[[^\]]` is a little easier to understand IMO.

Answer (score 1):

if i understand correctly ,a simple solution would be to replace all instances of "[", "]" and then split:

```
st = "The site uses the [stackoverlow api](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) to fetch all existing tags and create a"

st.replace("["," ").replace("]", " ").split()
```

this will give you :

```
['The', 'site', 'uses', 'the', 'stackoverlow', 'api', '(https://api.stackexchange.com/docs)', 'to', 'fetch', 'all', 'existing', 'tags', 'and', 'create', 'a']
```

of course you can also replace "(", ")" or any other manipulation to split the url as well.